# Negative margin on IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, margin

I have a list of products. Passing in the mouse over a product the box enlarges and you can see thumbnails of the other images of the product.

I found a solution only with css:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="boxProdotto"> ... <span class="thumbs"><img><img></span></div>
    <div class="boxProdotto"> ... <span class="thumbs"><img><img></span></div>
    <div class="boxProdotto"> ... <span class="thumbs"><img><img></span></div>
    <div class="boxProdotto"> ... <span class="thumbs"><img><img></span></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    ... other row with 4 boxes
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.boxProdotto{ 
    position: relative;
    width: 175.5px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    float: left;
    background: #FFF;
}
.boxProdotto .thumbs {
    display: none;
}
.boxProdotto:hover{
    border: 2px solid #9d3951;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 11px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin: -13px -13px -200px 0;
    z-index: 200;
}
.boxProdotto:hover .thumbs {
    display: block;
}
```

Because the height of the box in the state onmouseover changes depending on how many thumbnails are there, I decided to calculate with JQuery how much should be the margin-bottom:

JQuery:

```
// Set the attribute data-h with the normal height of the box
$(".boxProdotto").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-h', $(this).height());
});

// on mouse over set the margin bottom calculated
$(".boxProdotto").mouseover(function(){
    // margin-bottom = boxHeight - boxHeightOnMouseOver - border - paddingBottom
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', ( $(this).attr('data-h') - $(this).height() - 2 - 11));
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', 0);
});
```

This solution works with all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari Mac & Win) but in IE8 and IE9 there are mysteries! While on IE10 works well ... IE7 I could not test it but I think it not works..

With IE8 it seems that the negative margin that is applied has no effect. But the strange thing is that positioning the mouse over the image of the first product, the box enlarges and you see that the next line moves lower. But by moving the mouse over the thumbnails (staying on mouse over of the same box) then magically works and margin-bottom is applied!

Looking I found a lot of bugs / problems related to IE margin negative and Jquery onmouseover / onmouseout and my case seems to be a mix of both.

Also with IE is practically impossible to debug the page also using the Fantastic Developer Tools!

Comment: Did you gave a spin to the `zoom: 1;position: relative;` trick in your `.boxProdotto:hover` rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could try to do is using a conditional statement to detect IE8 and then add a class in jQuery to the element which needs margin-bottom.

```
 <!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <style>
    .marginBottomIE { bottom: -200px; }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

If you are using Modernizr you can just detect the browser using the class .ie8 which is added to the body.

**jQuery**

```
 if($('.ie8').length > 0){
        $('.boxProdotto').addClass('marginBottomIE');
    }
```

Then you can add a simple if condition after calculating the margin-bottom, for example:

```
if(marginBottom < 0){ $('.boxProdotto').addClass('marginBottomIE'); }
```

**CSS**

```
 .marginBottomIE { bottom: -200px; }
```

Hope this helps :)